Firestore Termination Issue on Flutter Web: "The client has already been terminated" Error After Clearing Persistence
I am using await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence(); to clear cached data after a user signs out.
According to the documentation, this should only be called after terminating the Firestore session.
However, when I attempt to retrieve data again after logging back in, I encounter the following error:
"The client has already been terminated"

Note: This issue only occurs on Flutter Web. It works fine on Flutter mobile.
As Flutter web is relative new, compared to Flutter mobile, is this maybe an actual bug?
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();

Are there any steps, which I'm missing? I already tried to recreate the whole Firebase app, but same error.
Reproducing the issue
To reproduce the issue where clearing the cached data after a user signs out causes an error on Flutter Web, follow these steps:
After Sign Out of User:
Call the following code to clear the cached data:
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();

Sign In User:
Attempt to sign the user back in.
Retrieve Data:
Try to retrieve data from Firestore. For example:
var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('your_collection').get();

Encounter Error:
Observe the following error message:
"FirebaseError: The client has already been terminated."

Flutter Version
3.19.6
cloud_firestore:
4.17.4
firebase_core:
2.31.1
This issue, was already requested here, but no answer that's why I wanted to bring the issue up again.
